# Is it right to close highly rated questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, voting, old-questions

I just came across this question via Google search results

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530787/simple-http-web-server

116 up votes, 60 users have marked it as a favorite question yet its closed as "not constructive"?!

Is it right to closed it based on the decision of 5 users when 116 other users find it helpful?

Comment: People thought it was a good question five years ago when site standards were very different. If that same question were posted today (assuming it weren't a duplicate), it would be quickly closed for not following current (and much better) standards for question quality.

Comment: It's looking for a product recommendation, which is off-topic.

Comment: Popular != on-topic/suitable

Comment: It is a shopping question with 15 valid answers.  Why does it need more?  Even Google doesn't think it is a useful question, pretty rare, just query "python simple http server" to get the answer from the kind of sites that don't mind maintaining these kind of questions.

Comment: Ugh, that isn't even programming related.

Comment: Cast first vote to reopen, good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of upvotes/downvotes on a question has no influence on how right it is to close it.

If the question really does deserve to be open, and enough people believe that it should be open, then it only takes 5 reopen votes to open it back up.

It's not like those 5 close voters can veto the other 116.  If the 116 are still around, have sufficient reputation, and still want it open, they can reopen it easy.

Comment: That's a nice answer, much better than all the comments up there. Now I believe in the system we have inhere again.